# Deploy failed Netlify

Tags: javascript, html, css, deployment, netlify

I'm getting the following error

```
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/package.json'
```

Here's the full build log:

```
2:27:28 PM: Waiting for other deploys from your team to complete
2:27:30 PM: Build ready to start
2:27:32 PM: build-image version: b0258b965567defc4a2d7e2f2dec2e00c8f73ad6
2:27:32 PM: build-image tag: v3.4.1
2:27:32 PM: buildbot version: e1f4178b0d9779ebad1b11d5b54739f82fed3c22
2:27:32 PM: Building without cache
2:27:32 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
2:27:32 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
2:27:32 PM: git clone https://github.com/EitharAlotoom95/Eithar-Website-
2:27:33 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
2:27:34 PM: Starting build script
2:27:35 PM: Installing dependencies
2:27:35 PM: Python version set to 2.7
2:27:36 PM: v12.18.0 is already installed.
2:27:36 PM: Now using node v12.18.0 (npm v6.14.4)
2:27:36 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
2:27:36 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
2:27:36 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.1, read from environment
2:27:38 PM: Using ruby version 2.7.1
2:27:38 PM: Using PHP version 5.6
2:27:38 PM: 5.2 is already installed.
2:27:38 PM: Using Swift version 5.2
2:27:38 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
2:27:38 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
2:27:38 PM: go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
2:27:38 PM: go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
2:27:38 PM: Installing missing commands
2:27:38 PM: Verify run directory
2:27:39 PM: ​
2:27:39 PM: ┌─────────────────────────────┐
2:27:39 PM: │        Netlify Build        │
2:27:39 PM: └─────────────────────────────┘
2:27:39 PM: ​
2:27:39 PM: ❯ Version
2:27:39 PM:   @netlify/build 3.3.5
2:27:39 PM: ​
2:27:39 PM: ❯ Flags
2:27:39 PM:   deployId: 5f5224a05574348ce34178f9
2:27:39 PM:   mode: buildbot
2:27:39 PM: ​
2:27:39 PM: ❯ Current directory
2:27:39 PM:   /opt/build/repo
2:27:39 PM: ​
2:27:39 PM: ❯ Config file
2:27:39 PM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
2:27:39 PM: ​
2:27:39 PM: ❯ Context
2:27:39 PM:   production
2:27:39 PM: ​
2:27:39 PM: ┌───────────────────────────────────┐
2:27:39 PM: │ 1. Build command from Netlify app │
2:27:39 PM: └───────────────────────────────────┘
2:27:39 PM: ​
2:27:39 PM: $ npm run build
2:27:39 PM: npm ERR! code ENOENT
2:27:39 PM: npm ERR! syscall open
2:27:39 PM: npm ERR! path /opt/build/repo/package.json
2:27:39 PM: npm ERR! errno -2
2:27:39 PM: npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/package.json'
2:27:39 PM: npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
2:27:39 PM: npm ERR! enoent
2:27:39 PM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2:27:39 PM: npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2020-09-04T11_27_39_874Z-debug.log
2:27:39 PM: ​
2:27:39 PM: ┌─────────────────────────────┐
2:27:39 PM: │   "build.command" failed    │
2:27:39 PM: └─────────────────────────────┘
2:27:39 PM: ​
2:27:39 PM:   Error message
2:27:39 PM:   Command failed with exit code 254: npm run build
2:27:39 PM: ​
2:27:39 PM:   Error location
2:27:39 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
2:27:39 PM:   npm run build
2:27:39 PM: ​
2:27:39 PM:   Resolved config
2:27:39 PM:   build:
2:27:39 PM:     command: npm run build
2:27:39 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
2:27:39 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/dist
2:27:40 PM: Caching artifacts
2:27:40 PM: Started saving build plugins
2:27:40 PM: Finished saving build plugins
2:27:40 PM: Started saving pip cache
2:27:40 PM: Finished saving pip cache
2:27:40 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
2:27:40 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
2:27:40 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
2:27:40 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
2:27:40 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
2:27:40 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
2:27:40 PM: Started saving go dependencies
2:27:40 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
2:27:42 PM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
2:27:42 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
2:27:42 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
2:27:42 PM: Finished processing build request in 10.743452323s
```

Answer (score 14):

While building the site using netlify, use command "CI= npm run build" instead of default "npm run build"

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is removing /build from your .gitignore and then removing the build command (yarn build or npm run build) from the build settings in netlify.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, switching to Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 helped.

1. Go to: *Site settings* > *Build & deploy* > *Build image selection* > *Edit settings*.
2. Choose **Ubuntu Xenial 16.05**.
3. Save and rerun deployment.

[image: Build image selection]

Note:

- If you build/deploy an older site, and you need to use an older version of the dependency (Node, npm, Yarn, PHP, etc.), set version in the *Environment variables* section. Read more on [Build environment variables](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables/) at Netlify documentation.

Answer (score 1):

My deployment was also failing, the command I was using

```
CI=npm run build
```

I didn`t notice before, but when I added extra space after "CI=" and modified the command as shown below, it worked for me

```
CI= npm run build
```

Netify use "CI" environment variable for Continuous Integration

Answer (score 0):

Experienced a similar issue with Deploying on Netlify after switching from Gatsby to Hugo

This worked for me:

On your Netlify Deploy Settings, under build, place this
Build Settings: `hugo --gc`

[image]

Then Clear the cache and re-run the Deploy to trigger the build once more.

Answer (score 0):

use build command CI=false npm run build
Netlify somehow treats warnings as errors, CI=false says , just deploy ,dont worry about warnings
`CI=false npm run build`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).